# How to combine matchers

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-test

I have a test like:

```dart
const myText = 'This is my test';

expect(myText, contains('This'));
expect(myText, contains('test'));
```

How can I combine those 2 matchers to have only 1 `expect` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the matchers with [`allOf`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_expect/allOf.html):

```dart
const myText = 'This is my test';

expect(myText, allOf([contains('This'), contains('test')]));
```

More generally, you can combine any matchers using:

- [`allOf`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_expect/allOf.html) as a logical `&`.
- [`anyOf`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_expect/anyOf.html) as a logical `||`.
- [`isNot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_expect/isNot.html) as a logical `!`.